# Replacing "." with "," using VBA in Excel leed to loesing separator in many rows

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have an issue while using VBA in order to replace "." with "," in four columns B, C, D, E, which contain decimals.

I'm using the code below to perform replacement, but the problem is that in many cells the dot is not replaced with coma, instead it disappear.

```vb
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:E" & LastRow).Select
With Selection
   .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=","
End With
```

Any ideas why it happen? Or how to prevent that?
When I do it manually using ctrl+h, it works properly, but i would like to automatize it.

The data file I'm working on contain approximately 6k rows and 165 columns, can the size be the issue?

Comment: What kind of data is that?

Comment: If your cell is formatted as number and the thousands separator is not selected then if you try to replace `.` with `,` then the cell which have decimals will behave exactly the way you described. `12345.67` will become `1234567`

Comment: This seems like it might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need to do this?  What problem are you really trying to solve?  Perhaps your solution of replacing dot with comma is not the ideal solution for whatever your problem is.

Comment: @GSerg - numbers with decimals

Comment: @SiddharthRout - They are set as general by default, so you suggest to first change format to number with thousands separator, and then perform replacement?

Comment: If you replace decimal with comma then rhey will not be decimals anymore. Are you okay with that?

Comment: You have numbers with wrong decimal dots, [stored as strings](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365), then you correct the dots which makes it a number? If so, then the dots should only disappear on whole numbers, at which point apply the appropriate number format to the cells.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Raw data downloaded uses . as decimal separator, I have to change it manually every day before I will run a macro which will build a database of those data and send daily report, all reports are build using coma as decimal separator (macro works on a network computer) so if this won't be changed all the calculations won't be performed.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - no, i need them to be still decimals, but separated with coma not dot.

Comment: ah i understood what you are doing. Can you test one small thing for me?. In Immediate window in VBE just run this `?Application.decimalseparator`. I think it is `.` In such a case if you replace `.` with `,` and your cell doesn't have a thousand separator then after the replacing the `,` will disappear. Also in this case you replacing `.` with `,` will not be of any use. For this to work, the `Application.decimalseparator` has to be `,`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.decimalseparator

Comment: @SiddharthRout  - it is , but I found a solution, by just changing the format, without replacing dot with coma

Comment: If changing the format does the trick, then you are all set.  However, if you find that doesn't work, the next step would be to **import** the data using either the legacy wizard or Power Query, and setting the format of the data being **imported** at that time. Then it will convert to a "real" number which you can format however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

So this issue can be resolved just by changing the format, no need to use replace function.

```vb
Range("B2:E" & LastRow).Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "##.00"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```